# restoring a live tooth

Tags: diet, micronutrients, cavity, legumes

I just recently have had an amalgam filling fall out from a tooth after it has been in there for at least half my life and now there is a large hole in the tooth. I don't trust dentists because I read they have done bad things to patients such as give root canals which kills the nerve and/or crowns which prevents nutrients from entering the tooth.

What I want to do is repair the hole myself through diet since others have been (at least partially) successful. Some healed their cavities up and some claimed to have almost restored their teeth.

Since the hole began, I opted for more of a raw diet. I go for things like grass-fed butter, cocoa, water, vegetable juice, and I'm starting to now go on goats milk instead of regular cows milk.

I read that some things (like grains and legumes) have phytic acid which is supposed to deplete minerals from your body.

I also read that an acidic diet helps bacteria cause cavities.

Because of this, I'm lost. Am I doing the right thing with consuming what I mentioned? and how do I successfully incorporate vitamin C and regular meals into all this without making my mouth acidic enough for bacteria to make cavities? or will I just have to go with just a raw diet?

Any advice?

All the better if whoever responds has successfully regrown a tooth in the past.

Comment: Can you provide some links showing people that have healed cavities through diet, from a site that isn't trying to sell a product that claims it can do that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLEOdma_K00 and http://www.thehealthyhomeeconomist.com/photographic-proof-cavities-heal/

Comment: @Mike - if you have sources tht discuss how you can cure carious teeth, can you please clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: I meant actual studies. The youtube link is a testimonial for the book you cite, and Dr. Smith is also affiliated with a traditional dentists office, that does do fillings, etc. I would like to see more scientific evidence, as this would be an amazing discovery.

Comment: Please avoid answering in comments.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no evidence in reputable sources that any diet can restore a partially removed tooth to a full tooth again.

Any source you do encounter which proposes such a possibility is highly likely to benefit from such a claim (i.e. there exists a conflict of interest between the claim and the truth.)

There is, however, a large body of sound research on the repair of carious teeth via fillings, root canals, etc.

<sub>[Outcome of direct restorations placed within the general dental services in England and Wales (Part 1): Variation by type of restoration and re-intervention](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0300571205001417)</sub>
<sub>[Tooth survival following non-surgical root canal treatment: a systematic review of the literature](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2591.2009.01671.x/abstract?userIsAuthenticated=false&deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=)</sub>
<sub>[MANUAL FOR THE ATRAUMATIC RESTAURATIVE TREATMENT APPROACH TO CONTROL DENTAL CARIES](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yupin_Songpaisan/publication/228553340_Manual_for_the_Atraumatic_Restaurative_Treatment_approach_to_control_dental_caries/links/02e7e51f0ef4f102d1000000.pdf)</sub>